# Noncanonical isomorphism of spaces of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra

Let $\pi: V \to M$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional vector bundle over $M$. Are the spaces of differential forms $\Omega^i(V)$, $\Omega^i(V^*)$ noncanonically isomorphic? If so, how do I see this? Is there a place where this is proved or disproved?

Comment: It depends on what kind of isomorphism you have in mind. If as vector spaces, true but uninteresting. If as vector bundles, generally false.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm a little confused. Since complex wasn't specified, I'm assuming real bundles are meant, and all real bundles are isomorphic to their duals by picking a fiberwise metric, and hence so are the exterior bundles $\Lambda^i V \cong \Lambda^i V^*$ and the bundles of $V$-valued forms $\Lambda^i T^*M \otimes V \cong \Lambda^i T^*M \otimes V^*$, whichever the OP means. Are you referring to complex vector bundles are am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had in mind complex bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post just consolidates the comments.

If $V$ is a real vector bundle, a fiberwise inner product on $V$ determines an isomorphism $V \to V^*$ by $v \mapsto \langle v, -\rangle$. So anything else you could possibly do to $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic: in particular, it determines an isomorphism $\Lambda^i T^*M \otimes V \to \Lambda^i T^*M \otimes V^*$. This, then, defines an isomorphism of the spaces of sections (as $C^\infty(M)$-modules) $\Omega^i(V) \to \Omega^i(V^*)$.

However, if $V$ is a complex vector bundle, this is not usually true. One class of obstructions are the [Chern classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class). We have $c_i(V^*) = (-1)^i c_i(V)$, and so if $V \cong V^*$, then $2c_{2n+1}(V)=0.$ (There might be 2-torsion in the relevant cohomology groups, so that these don't literally vanish, but don't worry too much about this point.) Now, as vector spaces, $\Omega^i(V) \cong \Omega^i(V^*)$ for uninteresting cardinality reasons, but they will usually not be isomorphic as $C^\infty(M;\Bbb C)$-modules.